# Move div without animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code it works perfectly, but I want to change .animate effect with something more efficient. I don't want css' transition but something that move divs without showing movement. I need to do it "instantly".

```
$(document).on("click",".box",function(){
    var transparent = $(".transparent");
    var transparent_left = transparent.offset().left;
    var transparent_top = transparent.offset().top;
    var box = $(this);
    var width = parseInt(box.outerWidth());
    var this_top = box.offset().top;
    var this_left = box.offset().left;
    var result;

    if(transparent_top === (this_top + width)
    && transparent_left === this_left){ 
        change_score();
        box.finish().animate({top: "+="+width}, 100);
        transparent.finish().animate({top: "-="+width}, 100, function(){animate_callback(result)});
    }else if(transparent_top === this_top
    && transparent_left === (this_left + width)){ 
        change_score();
        box.finish().animate({left: "+="+width}, 100);
        transparent.finish().animate({left: "-="+width}, 100, function(){animate_callback(result)});
    }else if(transparent_top === this_top 
    && (transparent_left + width) === this_left){ 
        change_score();
        box.finish().animate({left: "-="+width}, 100);
        transparent.finish().animate({left: "+="+width}, 100, function(){animate_callback(result)});
    }else if((transparent_top + width) === this_top
    && transparent_left === this_left){ 
        change_score();
        box.finish().animate({top: "-="+width}, 100);
        transparent.finish().animate({top: "+="+width}, 100, function(){animate_callback(result)});
    }
});
```

Comment: "Instantly" doesn't make sense; Any animation implies a time period (even a very small one) of a transition from a state A to a state B. Can you create a working snippet or point to an example online that shows what you're trying to achieve?
I assume your animation is not fast enough or the properties you're animating are not producing the visual result you're trying to achieve.

Comment: But this is what I want. Just change positions without animation.
You can see an example here: http://codepen.io/rafail/pen/qqNwoY
I understand that you are a Greek person, and if you want we can speak in Greek to understand me better.

Comment: do you mind showing a wireframe or pasting your HTML (before any interaction takes place) and the desired result?

Comment: the example you're posting _has_ animations.

Comment: Yes, the above example it was made by me. If I knew how to do it, i didn't ask about it.

To explain better. I want something like this when click:  $("img1").attr("src","img2.src"); $("img2").attr("src","img1.src"); but for divs positions

Comment: George Katsanos, I think that the best solution for that I was asking is the one which I marked as correct, but your thinking about faster animation it's much prettier. :)

I apologize for my bad english! Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use **transfer** or **animation** the ways are remained is:

Set your div

```
position: absolute;
```

and change top, left, right, bottom of your div by javascript.

2. If you don't want position absolute you can change the location of div by changing it's margins.

Answer (score 2):

**Contemporary Solution** (using `transform: translateX();`)

You can apply a CSS `translate` using a javascript `onclick` event (without applying any CSS transition):

```js
var redBox = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

function moveWithoutAnimation() {
redBox.classList.toggle('moved');
}

redBox.addEventListener('click',moveWithoutAnimation,false);
```

```css
div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgb(255,20,0);
transform: translateX(0);
cursor: pointer;
}

div.moved {
transform: translateX(400px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

**Alternative Solution** (using `position: relative;`)

Here is an alternative solution which uses `position:` and `left:` (an older approach) instead of `transform: translateX()`:

```js
var redBox = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

function moveWithoutAnimation() {
redBox.classList.toggle('moved');
}

redBox.addEventListener('click',moveWithoutAnimation,false);
```

```css
div {
position: relative;
left: 0;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgb(255,20,0);
transform: translateX(0);
cursor: pointer;
}

div.moved {
left: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I want something like this but my code is intented for android webview application and older versions of android unfortunately don't support this css feature.

Comment: I was not aware of that when I wrote the first solution above. I have added a second solution employing an older approach (the one we would have used before `transform: translateX()`. Please re-consider accepting the complete answer above as your accepted answer. Thank you.

Comment: Both of your answers are correct but the other is simplest in my mind.